# Android Studio: Fail to upload image to mysql PHP

Tags: android, mysql, image, android-volley

I want to upload an image into mysql database (XAMPP) on Android Mobile Programming, but I've some problem with it. Based on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dV46_-AS4Pg, below are my edited code:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class picture extends AppCompatActivity {
private String encodedImage, image_name;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_picture);
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.
    DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"/MyCameraApp/IMG_Hello.jpg");
    ImageView mImgView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
    mImgView1.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) mImgView1.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,bos);
    byte[] bb = bos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(bb, Base64.DEFAULT);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.simpleTextView);
    textView.setText(encodedImage); //set text for text view
    makeRequest();
}
private void makeRequest() {
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, 
 "http://192.168.137.1/IRR/connection.php",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("encoded_string", encodedImage);
            map.put("image_name", "Hello.jpg");
            return map;
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(request);
}
}
```

The problem is the picture fail to upload in database, anyone can help me? thanks

Comment: `The problem is the picture fail to upload in database` Can be. But your Android code is uploading it to a php script. And hence has nothing to do with a database. So what is your problem? Who do you wanna blame?

Comment: `public void onResponse(String response) {
                }` ????????? Any reason you left it empty ?

Comment: `public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }` ????????? Any reason you left it empty ?

Comment: I have doing my php script that connect to database, it work well because I have tested with POSTMAN,the picture after encode can store in database

Comment: @greenapps I have follow the video for that part of the code

Comment: You better show some initiative and implement both listeners. If not you will stay unaware of what is going on.